# How to make two divs appear directly over each other

Tags: html, css

I want to make my button disappear and get replaced when the "SHOP" sign scrolls *over* it, but I can't think of how to do that. Currently, the 'buttons' are just a div's background. Help?

I understand that the fixed tag makes it so that the button stays in the same place, but how would I make it so that the SHOP sign ***scrolls over*** it?

Example Images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want **good answers** you better have an image of your desired outcome

Comment: he also wants to know how to make something dissapear once its underneath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css's style `position` property.

Example- Using `position: relative` along with `left: xpx;` `right:xpx;` may suit your needs.

Reference: 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

To make something "disappear", you may want to use CSS's `visibility` property:

```
document.getElementById("myP").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

and so all in all you can use `javascript` to move your objects, and when the object moves, check if the positions overlap. When you have detected the objects are overlapping, set the desired object's visibility to hidden.

Reference : 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp

Comment: But I want it to disappear when the shop sign goes over it

Comment: But even then, doesn't that hide the whole thing? I only want the part that's overlapped to hide

Comment: unfortuneately youre going to have to shrink your boxes programmatically as they go behind other boxes. Then once fully hidden you can make them dissappear with the visibility property. I believe thats the only way youre going to achieve what you want. Maybe you could programmatically splice your boxes and change the z-index of your boxes... but that seems like a lot of work for what youre trying to achieve!

Comment: Or you could overlay fake backgrounds behind your boxes and make the "back" box pass under the top box AND a fake background to make it look like its disappearing... just going to need to play with zindexes. Yes i realise its extremely hard to visualize what i wrote haha

Comment: Alright. I'll try to make sense of what I just read, and then play around with the z-indexes a bit.

Comment: I might as well just make the buttons scroll along with everything else, and be content with the background moving ;) Thankks anyways though!